# My Keurig is making a grinding noise, but isn’t pouring water

Tags: equipment, coffee-machines, cleaning

I don’t know what’s wrong, it is making this noise like grinding, no water is coming out, the water is however heating up, and the needle is working at punching a hole through the K-Cup. The only issue seems to be dispensing water. Anyone know how in Hades to fix it as I’m thinking the only solution might be to take it apart and reassemble it.

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the machine. Probably the pump is toast, though. Pumps are one of the most likely to fail parts in any automatic machine due to wear water puts on their parts. You should look for videos specific to your Keurig model to see what would be involved in replacing this part.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Keurig needs descaling (or a pin needle run through the hole in the puncturing point; especially if Hot-Chocolate was made). Also, I've found that if the machine was left on for hours prior to trying to make a cup it would not co-operate. Of course, the remedy being let it cool-down (for ten minutes or so).